# JavaScript: How to use WebStorm debugger with ava

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, debugging, webstorm, ava

This is not question, just answer:

1. Create run/debug configuration, type Node.js
2. Select your node interpreter
3. As node parameter insert your ava bin and parameter `--verbose`

   For me it's: `./node_modules/.bin/ava  --verbose`
4. Select your working directory
5. Done, now you can debug

The magic is in `--verbose`, I have no idea why it works that way, but it does.

[image: WebStorm screenshot]

Comment: Actualy I'have idea why it works, it may be because with verbose, webstorm have enough time, or needed outputs to attach debugger to all "sessions"

Comment: Please specify what exactly you are asking.. are you asking why `--verbose` works the way it does?

Comment: If you want to provide some useful answer for others (for a problem that you have faced) ... better make a proper question and then answer it yourself. DO NOT create *"This is not question, just answer"* stuff

Answer (score 0):

Create a new node test runner with following configuration:

**Node interpreter**: whatever version of node that you are using that is compatible with your ava version

**Working directory**: `~/Documents/Work/projectRootDir`

**Javascript file**: `node_modules/ava/cli.js`

**Application parameters**: `-v outdir/testFile e.g. /dist/test/controllers/test.js`[image: exampleimageofconfig]

There you go, now you can run and debug AVA with the best javascript IDE instead of console logging!
I'm quite sure that vscode config will be quite similar

Comment: `cli.js` seems to have moved to `node_modules/ava/entrypoints/cli.mjs`. With that configuration, running the test works, but debugging does not (execution seems to hang at the very beginning, and no tests are run). Node 18.7.1, Ava 5.3.1, WebStorm 2023.2.1, which has just celebrated [7 years of requests for Ava support](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-21788)!

Answer (score -1):

I have no idea why/how it works for you - configuration is definitely wrong. 
With your configuration, `--inspect-brk` is passed to ava, not to Node.js, and thus treated as your application argument. You should have specified `node_modules/.bin/ava` as **JavaScript file:** in your **Run** configuration instead of specifying it as a Node parameter, to make sure that Node debug arguments are passed before the application main file. `--verbose` can be passed as application parameter.

See also https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/debugging-with-webstorm.md

Comment: The [recipe at that link](https://github.com/avajs/ava/blob/master/docs/recipes/debugging-with-webstorm.md) is marked outdated and indeed doens't work.